# How do I split data in a variable

Tags: variables, split

I want to delete some of the numbers in on variable

My data is this:

```
        A                         
ID
1   2212807790       
2   1512300101       
3   3111560909       
4   1201017007       
5   1711344658       
6   1817302002       
..
```

I need a variable `B` without the last four numbers in varible `A`:

```
       A                B          
ID
1   2212807790       221280
2   1512300101       151223
3   3111560909       311156
4   1201017007       120101
5   1711344658       171134
6   1817302002       181730
..
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Which data structure? Please post some code.

Comment: Just divide `A` by 10000?

Comment: These are examples of ID data with birthdates first and ID number as the last four numbers. I need the birthdates and need to have the last four numbers removed.

Comment: The only code I used untill now is to read in the file: data <-read.csv2("test.csv")

Answer (score 0):

```python
#reading csv
bData=pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
#copying column A to a list
myList=bData['A']
for i in range(len(myList)):

    myStr=str(myList[i])
    myList[i]=myStr[0:(len(str(myList[i]))-4)]
#making the newly created list with truncated columns A as column B
bData['B']=myList
```